# Cropping image on the fly to display in a list using Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, system.drawing

I'm trying to have my JPEGs (portrait and landscape) cropped from the center to display as 1:1 on a product list.

Here is what I tried so far:

ViewModel:

```
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public List<HomeProductList> ProductList { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class HomeProductList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; } // Ex: 2021031122101047389.jpg
    }
```

Linq query:

```
var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
var ImagePath = "/img/";

var products = (from p in _context.Products
                join pd in _context.ProductDescribeFulls on p.Id equals pd.ProductId
                select new HomeProductList
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Photo = ImagePath + pd.Photo
                });

foreach (HomeProductList prod in products)
{
    if (prod.Photo != null)
    {
        prod.Thumbnail = ResizeImage(Image.FromFile(prod.Photo), new Size(45, 45));
    }
}
```

ResizeImage Method:

```
public static Image ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size destinationSize)
{
    var originalWidth = imgToResize.Width;
    var originalHeight = imgToResize.Height;

    //how many units are there to make the original length
    var hRatio = (float)originalHeight / destinationSize.Height;
    var wRatio = (float)originalWidth / destinationSize.Width;

    //get the shorter side
    var ratio = Math.Min(hRatio, wRatio);

    var hScale = Convert.ToInt32(destinationSize.Height * ratio);
    var wScale = Convert.ToInt32(destinationSize.Width * ratio);

    //start cropping from the center
    var startX = (originalWidth - wScale) / 2;
    var startY = (originalHeight - hScale) / 2;

    //crop the image from the specified location and size
    var sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(startX, startY, wScale, hScale);

    //the future size of the image
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(destinationSize.Width, destinationSize.Height);

    //fill-in the whole bitmap
    var destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

    //generate the new image
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return bitmap;

}
```

Here I get this error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
/img/2021031122101047389.jpg
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /img/2021031122101047389.jpg
prod.Thumbnail = ResizeImage(Image.FromFile("/img/2021031122101047389.jpg"), new Size(45, 45));

But: http://localhost:903/img/2021031122101047389.jpg display my image!

When I try instead of a loop to resize during the query by calling the method like so:

```
...
Id = p.Id,
Thumbnail = ResizeImage(Image.FromFile(ImagePath + pd.Photo), new Size(45, 45)),
Photo = ImagePath + pd.Photo
...
```

I get this error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Drawing.Image ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing.Size)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Drawing.Image ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing.Size)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any good idea?

Comment: You probably should look up what _Model–View–Controller_ really is about.. - Did you test all parts without LINQ first?

Comment: @TaW what do you mean?

Comment: Mean by what???

Comment: @TaW I did test in LINQ witout the ResizeImage method and I can display the image in the original ratio. But How can I test it without LINQ? Can you provide me an exemple?

Comment: Your code runs fine here, using local files. So it may be a path issue..

Comment: Ok. How can it be a path issue if Photo = ImagePath + pd.Photo and http://localhost:903/img/2021031122101047389.jpg display my image correctly?

Comment: Well, log out the paths, so you can see them. Also you may want to add checks with File.Exists..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230732/discussion-between-philippe-and-taw).